# Calculate peaks of rows in matrix vectorized in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I've got a series of row vectors in a matrix. I want to calculate the peaks of each row and assign them to a new array.

Ex:

```
A = [1,3,4,2,1,3,1;5,6,7,6,7,6,5]
[peaks, inds] = myfunc(A)

peaks =

 4     3
 7     7


inds =

 3     6
 3     5
```

This would be easy to do with a for loop, just take

```
[peaks(i,:), inds(i,:)] = findpeaks(A(i,:))
```

and iterate i. I want to know if it's possible to do in a vectorize way though. It shouldn't copy a lot of things in memory or anything like that, just cleanly calculate it row by row.

Things I've tried:

```
indices = 1:size(A,1);
[peaks(indices,:), inds(indices,:)] = findpeaks(A(indices,:))
Error using findpeaks
Expected X to be a vector.

Error in findpeaks>parse_inputs (line 90)
validateattributes(Xin,{'numeric'},{'nonempty','real','vector'},...

Error in findpeaks (line 71)
[X,Ph,Pd,Th,Np,Str,infIdx] = parse_inputs(Xin,varargin{:});
```

Comment: What happens if the same peak is next to each other? i.e. `5 6 7 7 7 6 5`

Comment: I think it just chooses the first one. But that's really an internal issue in the built in function findpeaks(data). What I'm having trouble with is applying it to each row, and distribute it to the resulting matrix.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with your code. Before running your code, try `clear all` and change the name of `peaks` variable since `peaks` is also a built-in function

Comment: What I was asking was: in your ideal version, what would you want it to do? Just one peak or multiple? I was considering code which did not use the built-in findpeaks